# How to send message via Request Dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk, dialog

I'm trying a apps using Facebook Requests Dialog.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
I can send my request using the sample code in above page 
with the message
 'You should learn more about this awesome game.'.
For my friends, they can receive the request, but there is no message.
How can I send the message via Requests Dialog and
How can my friends see my message when they receive my request?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

as of 12 july 2011 - facebook started ignoring that parameter... it says so on the link you posted... you should allow your users to fill out the message field after you display the send dialog to them...

Comment: Thank you, I found the msg in Application Requests Tab.